# Typeahead -- Insert autocompletion result on Enter press

Tags: jquery, twitter, autocomplete, typeahead.js

When a user types in the typeahead field and then presses Enter key, the form is submitted. This is not very intuitive, because instead of sumbitting the form the user expects that the autocomplete result to be inserted into the typeahead field.

I need to modify the detault Typeahead behavior on Enter press in the following way:

not submit the form;
to insert the first autocompleted item from the suggestions menu to the typeahead field;
close the Typeahead suggestions menu.
After browsing the internet, I've come to something like below:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#typeahead', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {            
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectables = $('#typeahead').siblings(".tt-menu").find(".tt-selectable");
        if (selectables.length > 0){
             $(selectables[0]).trigger('click');    
        }
        $('#typeahead').typeahead('close');            
    }
});
```

This almost works, except the Typeahead suggestions menu is not closed.

Can you help me to understand why the `$('#typeahead').typeahead('close');` doesn't work? Or is there some more elegant solution?

Comment: It doesn't submit the form It simply selects the highlighted field. I don't know why you need to use the above code. Here is the fiddle that demonstrates this behavior. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ncZJn/322/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for some reason. For example, when I enter 'Ala', it autocompletes 'Alabamaundefined'. The same is for all other suggestions, to all of them it appends 'undefined'.

Comment: Now it works fine. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ncZJn/325/

Comment: Thanks @geekowls, but I have a large JSON data source and initialize typeahead like in Prefetch example: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ How to adapt your fiddle to that?